# How does screen savers work on Mac OS X and Linux?

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform, screensaver

In Windows a screen saver is just an executable with a *.scr* extension dumped in the system32, and it is controlled with three switches (/p, /c and /s, I think).

How does screen savers work on Mac OS X and Linux? Do they work similarly in Mac OS X and Linux (Gnome, KDE, Ubuntu, or wherever the difference is) or is it completely different?

Also, can they be developed in C#/Mono?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screensaver system in OSX is that a screensaver (typically, but not necessarily) is an Objective-C library, extending a base class to implement methods such as drawing, a preference pane, a preview mode and so on.

There is a good tutorial on writing them [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000088.php).

While Objective-C is the language expected, it is straightforward enough to couple together a C/C++ implementation behind the Objective-C API.

There is an API (a bridge) to allow other languages to inter-operate with Objective-C APIs. This is used, for example, [here](http://code.google.com/p/pastels/) to allow OSX screen savers written in Python. I imagine a similar approach is feasible for Mono.

[xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) is now developed mostly on OSX, and uses the OSX screensaver API there and something else on X11.

Answer (score 1):

For X11, I'm pretty sure you can target [xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) and have it work in GNOME.  Not sure about KDE.  But xscreensaver has long been the dominant package on Linux.

IIRC, the programming model for xscreensaver is that you write it as any old app that draws an X window.  Then it can be invoked with "`-root`" and it should draw on the root window.  But that's probably not all there is to it.

The [xscreensaver FAQ](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html) seems to suggest that GNOME and KDE each have their own screensaver frameworks.  But [the Wikipedia article for gnome-screensaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome-screensaver) says it's a wrapper for xscreensaver.

Comment: A professor of mine said that X11 screensavers are merely full-screen programs that listen for any kind of keyboard/mouse signal to make it quit.  He was one of those old, out of touch academics though, so I don't know how true that was.

Comment: @supercheetah: Actually, it's even simpler than that. Try running any of the screensavers in `/usr/lib/xscreensaver` manually. The screensaver harness (`xscreensaver`, `kscreensaver`, `gnome-screensaver`) is responsible for grabbing the keyboard and mouse and killing the screensaver. You don't have to reinvent that wheel.